# Change dictionary keys from string to integer

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I am trying to convert the keys of a dictionary from being strings into integers using this code:

```
b = {"1":0,"2":0,"3":0,"4":0,"5":0}

for newkey in b:
        newkey[key] = int(newkey[key])
print b
```

However this keeps producing the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\counter2", line 22, in <module>
    newkey[key] = int(newkey[key])
NameError: name 'key' is not defined
```

I want the final output to look like this:

```
b = {1:0,2:0,3:0,4:0,5:0}
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: you never defined `key`, exactly as the error says. perhaps you want `for key in b:  newkey = int(key)   b[newkey] = b[key]`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this code

```
for newkey in b:
        newkey[key] = int(newkey[key])
```

`key` has never been defined before. Perhaps you meant `newkey`? Instead, simply reconstruct the dictionary with dictionary comprehension, like this

```
>>> b = {"1": 0, "2": 0, "3": 0, "4": 0, "5": 0}
>>> {int(key):b[key] for key in b}
{1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0}
```

Or you can use [`dict.iteritems()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems), like this

```
>>> {int(key): value for key, value in b.iteritems()}
{1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

You never defined `key`

You can do

```
new_b = {int(old_key): val for old_key, val in b.items()}
# int(old_key) will be the key in the new list
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looping the dictionary `b`, you may want to do

```
for newkey in b:
    b[newkey] = int(b[newkey])
print b
```

But this doesn't make sense at all, it changes the "value", not the "key".

You may want to do this instead:

```
b = {int(key):value for key, value in b.items()}
```